# Why does one require that $\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz=F(\gamma(b))-F(\gamma(a))$ must have piece-wise regular/smooth $\gamma$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why does one require that $$\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz=F(\gamma(b))-F(\gamma(a))$$ must have piece-wise regular/smooth $\gamma$?

How is the requirement seen?

Comment: That requirement seems more for convenience. Indeed, contour integral will easily extend to rectifiable curves.

Answer (score 3):

$\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$

Comment: Aah. Of course.